# what is the best way to learn the database connectivity in .net

Tags: .net, ado.net

I like to learn about database connectivity in .net, Where i will start for that

Answer (score 5):

I would start with some [ADO.NET tutorials](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/ADODotNet/Lesson01.aspx):

> This lesson is an introduction to
>   ADO.NET.  It introduces primary
>   ADO.NET concepts and objects that you
>   will learn about in later lessons. 
>   Here are the objectives of this
>   lesson:
>
> - Learn what ADO.NET is.
> - Understand what a data provider is.
> - Understand what a connection object is.
> - Understand what a command object is.
> - Understand what a DataReader object is.
> - Understand what a DataSet object is.
> - Understand what a DataAdapter object is.